# cant use npm and gem in powershell and git bash anymore

Tags: powershell, git-bash

I tried to get git working on PowerShell as it didn't recognise the command.

Git works now, unfortunately anything else doesn't work anymore. This is also true for git bash (using windows 7). This is quite annoying.

In git bash it says: `sh.exe: grunt: command not found`

In PowerShell it says something like: `the term grunt is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`.

The path to my git folder is as follows: `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd`

Comment: sounds like you no longer have the environment variables set. I haven't tried git, but I use ruby, just with basic install, and gem install works in a PS shell session.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what I did wrong was, I deleted the entire path line and added the git one, so that's why only git worked. I had to manually add the paths (stacking them after eachother) to nodejs and ruby to make everything work again.

for example: C:\Program Files\nodejs